# Create custom date MSI Attribute

Tags: magento2.4.3, msi

Is it possible to create a custom attribute for MSI Stock data at the store level and add it in the following table at Admin Product edit or do we just have to use the extension/custom attribute to achieve custom functionality for the MSI?

It Would be a great help for any reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There will be two options

1. Use an extension
   https://www.wyomind.com/magento2/multi-stock-inventory-custom-attributes-magento-2.html
2. Create a custom setup script:
   On MSI I would suggest add Source Type ExtensionAttribute to the Source entity. So that you could use that attribute when released.
   you can do it by yourself. Here is Magento documentation to use - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Comment: yes I already know this but I'm asking if there is any other way or code reference to achieve this functionality

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. You can take reference -

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Thanks,
Rashi

Comment: yes I already know this but I'm asking if there is any other way or code reference to achieve this functionality